# Can't get Facebook comments from my post to the website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to show the comments from my facebook page post on my PHP website. I like the comments to be synced, so where the user enters comments on the facebook post of my page, it will automatically show up on my website. I know how to create the comment box, but it's doesn't pull the comments from the page.

for the comment box I have:

```
<div class='fb-comments' data-href='https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.182291248558753.39531.182290545225490&type=1&l=d607ba4dcc' data-num-posts='3' data-width='470'></div>
```

I am trying to show the comments that were left on my post, but it's not pulling it. I have looked at the graph API but can't figure out which on get the comments and how to get the so called "primary key" for the comments.

I have looked at the following fql:

1. Stream: but I don't know what the "post_id" is supposed to be. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/
2. Comment: but I don't know what the "post_id","object_id", or "xid"  would be for a post in a page of the an album. I even tried to replace the URL in the example post they had, but it seems like FB FQL can't parse that kinda url. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/

Even when we get a list of comments, I am not sure how the fb:comments plugin can use the stream to populate my page, don't know if it's possible!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Facebook PHP SDK for this which you can get from [github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk). You can then use it to retrieve the comments from the post and store them in a database, updating every now and then to stay current. This will mean less requests to Facebook. When a user posts on your site using your form you can then send the post to Facebook using the SDK.

The problem with this method is that you will need to create an app and users will have to authorise the app for it to be able to post as them. So maybe it's not such a good idea, but I've typed all this in now so I'm not going to delete it.